# How to connect to private Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, raspberry-pi

I got some misunderstanding with how to connect to my private Blockchain.
So, I got private Blockchain and I can mine there. 
I activate there genesis.json file, made mew account for "coinbase".

For example, I activate my private Blockchain by geth:

> geth --rpc --rpcaddr "192.168.0.102" --rpcport "8585" --mine --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,miner" --networkid 57 --ipcpath "&APPDATA&\Ethereum\geth.ipc"

Here I put my laptop address (cause it runs there and it's port). Also, I got another computer. which is out of my local network. How can I get it to my chain? Not as miner, for example, just to send there some type information?

Also, the second problem is with my local network. My laptop has 192.168.0.102 and I connected to my WIFI Raspberry pi and it's address is 192.168.0.103. As far, as I see, they are both in my local network. So, how can I connect it to my Blockchain?

If I put there:

> geth --rpc --rpcaddr "192.168.0.102" --rpcport "8585" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,miner" --networkid 57 --ipcpath "&APPDATA&\Ethereum\geth.ipc"

I just start a new private Blockchain.

To be honest, I'm terribly confused. Or there is no way to connect to it, if I am not in a local network, not on one machine?

Thank you for understanding, I hope, I will get an answers.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have some issues that are appart of the Ethereum World.

In order to not adding more complexity to your process, [here](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0) you have a very well explained tutorial of how to create a private blockchain (wll done) and how to create a network arround it. You have photos and all of the commands and info about what you are doing and why.

If you have created yout private chain on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx , and that's not a server where you can connect from the external world (only if you are inside your local network) you won't be able to connect any externar-network PC to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please, tell me more detailed. I'va got another system now and got private blockchain on 3 virtual machines, and one of them is connected to external world (have access to Internet). Also I got port mapping on port 8545 to get to her local address. So, there are no way to connect as another node from laptop to this virtual machine ecosystem? So, I want to run geth on virtual machines, as they are syncronized and init same genesis.json on the laptop out of that local network. There is NO WAY to access as a node to that private blockchain on virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as `rpcaddr`. You can setup private blockchain and connect with it using these simple commands:

To initialize genesis block:

```
geth --identity "TestChain1" --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcport "8013" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "myPrivateNetwork" --port "30312" -networkid 1902 --nat "any" init "customGenesis.json" console
```

To connect to your private blockchain:

```
geth --identity "TestChain1" --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcport "8013" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,eth,admin,debug,miner" --datadir "myPrivateNetwork" --port "30312" -networkid 1902 --nat "any" --ipcpath "/home/prashant/.ethereum/geth.ipc" console
```

You can change the configs as you want. I have written a medium article for same. Maybe that can help [Setting up private blockchain](https://medium.com/@prashantprabhakarsingh/setting-private-blockchain-with-ethereum-and-geth-7c68760e939)